# RowDataPacket value undefined

Tags: javascript

When I run my code it returns my value as undefined which is strange because if I run the entire array it shows all data.

Here is the code:

```
console.log(appid_cards[x].cards);  (returns "undefined")
console.log(appid_cards[x].appid);  (returns "undefined")
console.log(appid_cards[x]);        (returns "appid=", "cards:")
```

for example this happens if I run a specific (existing row) :

```
console.log(appid_cards[x].cards);  (returns "undefined")
console.log(appid_cards[x].appid);  (returns "undefined")
console.log(appid_cards[x]);        (returns "appid: 400250, cards: 8")
console.log(x);                     (returns "0")
```

so the X works for the entire RowDataPacket, but if I want to select a key then it somehow doesn't work.

I also check if maybe x would become greated then the number of rows but that is no the case because it is run in a "for" loop and it cannot be greater than appid_cards.length, I can call the entire array but once I start to specify the "cards" or "appid" it returns undefined.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `"appid: 400250, cards: 8"` is that a string or an object? looks like a string to me

Comment: This is the exacts log "[ RowDataPacket { appid: 400250, cards: 8 } ]"

Comment: which browser? because, again, that doesn't look like an object - oh, wait, I see, appid_cards is an array of `RowDataPacket` ? whatever that is? (I guess you are using Chrome?)

Comment: The surrounding `[]` makes it look like each appid_cards[x] is an array of RowDataPacket ... i.e. you have a nested array perhaps?  what is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(appid_cards))` - or try `console.log(appid_cards[x][0].cards);`

Answer (score 0):

Found out that where I pushed the array something went wrong and fixed that piece of code, fixing this as well. Thanks for all the help !